# geth vs parity: light client comparison

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, light-clients

My computer is a laptop with a small SSD HDD, so I don't want to download the blockchain.

Hence, I want to use `--light` to connect to other computers which do have a copy of the blockchain.

[Parity's wiki page](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Light-Client) says that `--light` is experimental.

[geth's wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol) says that it is "under development".

How do they both compare in terms of:

- Protocol support
- Speed
- Robustness / Reliability
- Code maturity
- Features